# RunningCount webi Business Objects Formula

Tags: excel-formula, business-objects, webi

I am trying to produce a running count of salesid's for each distinct customer id.

I have tried this formula:

`=RunningCount([Order ID])ForAll([Query 1].[Brand Account ID])`

And unfortunately it yields this result:

[image]

We can see that where 'Count_of_Salesorder' == 12, it should have reset to 1 because the customer id has changed from B000115545 to B000159009

How can I achieve the running count of 'Order ID' for each distinct customer id? (Customer id is the field containing values that begin with 'B000')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify that you want the count to reset for each value of Brand Account ID.

```
=RunningCount([Order ID]; ([Brand Account ID]))
```

If you navigate to the RunningCount function with the Variable Editor and click on the "More on this function" link you will see its documentation.

[image]

[image]